# Related selects using jquery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I don't do a whole lot with jquery, so please forgive if this is a really entry level question.  I have two selects - broad categories of academic interests and then refined based on the first selection.  Firebug shows me getting the correct data back from the function, but I can't get it to build the 2nd select with that data.

```
<script>
   $("#general").change(function() {
     $.ajaxSetup({
        dataFilter: function(data, type){
          return type == 'json' ? data.replace(/^(\/{2})?/, '') : data;
        }
    });
    //get what they selected
    var selected = $("option:selected",this).val();
    //no matter what, clear the other DD
    $("#majors").children().remove().end().append("&lt;option value=\"\"&gt;-- Select a Majors --&lt;/option&gt;");
    //now load in new options of selected category
    if(selected == "") return;
        $.getJSON(remote.cfc?method=queryMajorsRemote&returnformat=json",{"cip_fam":selected}, function(res,code) {
          var newoptions = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < res.DATA.length; i++) {
            newoptions += "&lt;option value=\"" + res[i].id + "\"&gt;" + res[i].name + "&lt;/option&gt;";
          }
        $("#majors").children().end().append(newoptions);
    });
});
</script>
```

The HTML is very simple - just two selects - one with ID #general and the other with ID #majors.

A sample of the response data is:

```
[{"ID":422,"NAME":"Engineering"},{"ID":426,"NAME":"Engineering - Aerospace, Aeronautical and Astronautical"}]
```

Comment: When you want to create elements, you shouldn't be using HTML entity notation (`&lt;`) — use actual `<` and `>` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sample of the response data reported in the question, you have some issues:

- res.DATA.length  must be res.length
- res[i].id must be res[i].ID
- res[i].name must be res[i].NAME

In order to create a new option you may write on the fly, instead of string:

```
$('<option/>', {value: res[i].ID, text: res[i].NAME})
```

If you need to empty the second select box before appending options you may write:

```
$("#majors").empty()
```

The snippet:

```js
var res = [{"ID":422,"NAME":"Engineering"},{"ID":426,"NAME":"Engineering - Aerospace, Aeronautical and Astronautical"}];

$("#general").change(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        dataFilter: function (data, type) {
            return type == 'json' ? data.replace(/^(\/{2})?/, '') : data;
        }
    });
    //get what they selected
    var selected = $("option:selected", this).val();
    //no matter what, clear the other DD
    $("#majors").children().remove().end().append("&lt;option value=\"\"&gt;-- Select a Majors --&lt;/option&gt;");
    //now load in new options of selected category
    if (selected == "") return;
    //$.getJSON("http://localhost:63342/Projects/StackOverflow/1.json", {"cip_fam": selected}, function (res, code) {
        var optionToBeAppendedTo = $("#majors").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            optionToBeAppendedTo.append($('<option/>', {value: res[i].ID, text: res[i].NAME}));
        }
    //});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="general">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="majors">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much!!